# The offset function doesn't recognize address function reference to a cell in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I can't figure out why the Address function result (looks like this Sheetname!$D$10 doesn't work in the Offset function. When I write that same Sheetname!$D$10 directly into the function it works perfectly. All cells field data formats are General.
Can anybody give me some clues?

Comment: ADDRESS returns a string not a valid range reference.  Note that 66.6% of the time using address to create a valid address to be used in another formula can be avoided as it is volatile.  Please give more information as to what you are starting with and why and how you are using address and maybe we can give you a better method.  If not and you want to stay with the volatile functions, wrap the Address with INDIRECT which turns a string into a valid range reference.

Comment: Further to Scott’s answer…  *Any* time you create a reference using a formula, you have to  place formula inside an INDIRECT() function.  A function that returns `Sheetname!$D$10` is *not* the same as hardcoding in “Sheetname!$D$10”.  The Excel interpreter scans the formula looking for references like `B10` and maps those to a specific memory address very early in the process.  Later, it processes function calls.  By the time your function returns `B10` it’s too late, the process of resolving B10 to a memory address was already done.  INDIRECT says “resubmit this reference for interpretation.”